# Convention to stop defamation of religion

Tags: law, international-relations, international-law, religion, pakistan

Pakistani prime minister said that we shall be introduced a convention to stop the ‘’defamation of any religion’’ and this work will be supervised by jurist.

The question is: Is there any legal provisions are present in the law of all countries of the world to accept this convention or to support this convention?

Comment: If there is any convention about that, they would first start defining *defamation of any religion*: since Christianism could define Islam as a defamation itself, or atheism can be considered at a defamation of any, it would be hard to even start the discussion. Is Pakistani government ready to discuss about this definition?

Comment: It would directly conflict with the First Amendment to the US Constitution, for one.  Then WRT Islam in particular, it's been defaming my religion (to the limited extent I have one :-)) since its founding, so you'd have to start by editing out large parts of the Quran...

Comment: Also, what about science?  Say some religion (which shall remain nameless :-)) says its deity created the world a bit over 6000 years ago, yet geologists say it's more like 5 billion years old, paleontologists keep digging up all these odd fossils, biologists bring in genetic clocks...  Aren't they all defaming that religion?

Comment: Maybe we should ask [*Asia Bibi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia_Bibi_blasphemy_case) about defamation of religion in Pakistan?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are very few laws that are seen as being binding on all people.  Those that do exist (such as "crimes against humanity" or "crimes against peace") are not part of a conventional legal system.  There are no universal laws on religious defamation.

The short answer to your question is "No, there are no provisions in the law of all countries to accept this convention".

For contrast there is the Universal Declaration of Human Rights, which says:

> Article 18
>
> Everyone has the right to freedom of thought, conscience and religion; this right includes freedom to change his religion or belief, and freedom, either alone or in community with others and in public or private, to manifest his religion or belief in teaching, practice, worship and observance.
>
> Article 19
>
> Everyone has the right to freedom of opinion and expression; this right includes freedom to hold opinions without interference and to seek, receive and impart information and ideas through any media and regardless of frontiers.

In these articles, countries which signed the agreement (including Pakistan - one of the strongest supporters of this text in 1948) explicitly allow people to hold any belief, to hold and express their criticisms of any belief, and to change their beliefs.

A country may, by law, limit the exercise of these rights only for the sake of "securing due recognition and respect for the rights and freedoms of others and of meeting the just requirements of morality, public order and the general welfare in a democratic society".  You can limit the expression of criticism only to the extent required to maintain a safe and ethical society. Thus it may be reasonable to outlaw the insults against religion.

However these articles are aspirational, not binding.

The context of this is the actions of various bodies in Pakistan seeking extreme punishment against non-muslims for claimed insults against Islam. There is nothing in international law which condones, accepts or provides for this.

Answer (score 6):

A global convention to ban "defamation of any religion" is very unlikely to gain wide support among the more secular states in Europe and the Americas.

Why?

Because while these states do support [freedom of religion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_religion) and outlaw discrimination of people based on religion, they also hold another human right in very high regard: [Freedom of Speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_speech).

Freedom of speech includes the right to criticize ideas. When I think that the [flying spaghetti monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster) does not exist and any Pastafarian who believes in it is a delusional fool, then unlimited freedom of speech would give me the right to say so. But where do you draw the line between criticizing a religion and defaming a religion? Am I defaming the Pastafarian religion by calling them delusional fools? Possibly, because I am directly insulting a religious minority. Or am I already going too far just by claiming that the FSM does not exist? Where do you draw this line?

Two rights need to be valued against each other here: Freedom of religion and freedom of speech. The tendency in most secular countries is to generally value freedom of speech higher than freedom of religion, as long as the speech does not directly call for violence against a religious minority. In most countries I could say "Pastafarians are wrong in their believes" but I could not say "All Pastafarians should be killed".

On the other hand, many autoritarian governments have a tendency to abuse religious defamation laws to persecute political dissidents. This is especially the case where a government claims to have religious legitimation. When you would live in the fictional Pastafarian Republic of Raviolia where the government claims to rule in the name of the Flying Spaghetti Monster, then criticizing the government could be interpreted as defamation of the Pastafarian religion. So when theocratic governments want to get rid of critics but do not want to admit that they do politically motivated arrests, they often imprison them for violating laws against defamation of religion.

This practice gave religious defamation laws a rather bad reputation in the Western world and makes them rather unpopular.

Comment: This is a correct, albeit European-centric answer. For some/many (US) Americans, the ban on "All Pastafarians should be killed" is already a serious limitation on the freedom of speech. The same way bans on Nazism found in many European countries are. Lumping together the Americas and Europe together when discussing free speech is difficult because of the different perception on what free speech *is* in the US.

Comment: @DonFusili Yeah, in the US it's generally acceptable to say "The only good nazi is a dead nazi" but not okay to say "see that nazi over there? We/You should kill him."

Comment: @David Rice: Even the "should kill" might be acceptable.  (IANAL, though.)  But

Comment: To add more to the idea that this idea is far to simplistic it would be very easy to consider Pastafarianism as mocking other religions.  Should it be protected from all criticism because it's a religion or should it be banned because it is criticising other religions?  Who will decide that?  Should it be illegal to criticise Scientology (Scientologists seems to think so and they already take plenty of defamation law suits).  The worry seems to be that a poorly defined law will be enforced unevenly by people who are very conservative and likely involved with one specific religion.

Comment: Freedom of speech and religion aren't so much competing values, as **complimentary** values.  It's virtually impossible to have freedom of religion without freedom of speech, because most of the early religions tended to ([violently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_persecution)) prohibit any others.